# Print FixedDocument without using dialog for directory

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument, printdialog, fixeddocument

I want to print FixedDocument with `"Microsoft Print to PDF"` and without showing up dialog to choose directory. I know that I can do this by passing to `PrinterSettings`: `PrintFileName` and `PrintToFile` with `true`:

```
PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "C:\\Users"; 
PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
```

There is way to pass printer name:

```
printDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "printer name" );
```

but I do not know if it is possible or how to pass rest of parameters of printerSettings to PrintDialog.

To this moment I have used this method to print fixed document;

```
printDialog.PrintDocument(this.fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Description");
```

I know that there is way with passing printerSettings to `PrintDocument`, but now I do not know how to pass these `FixedDocument` to `PrintDocument`.

I will add that I have array of bits with png, which is converted to `BitmapImage`, then putted to wpf `UserControll` `Image` and eventually to `FixedDocument.Pages`.